# "Dynamic segment" in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Throughout the Ember.js documentation, one finds the concept of **dynamic segment** mentioned [at several places](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Aemberjs.com+%22dynamic+segment%22). What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating with a proper sample: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ZRaxz/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ZRaxz/)

**Edit due to questions in comments:**

In Ember, think of the `Router` mechanism as a State Machine: Each `Route` can be seen as a State. Sometimes tho, a state can have it's own little state machine within it. With that said: A `resource` is a state which you have possible child states. A `PersonRoute` can be defined as either as a `resource` our a `route` in the `<Application>.Router.map` callback; it really depends on your end goal. For example, if we think of a resource for a list of people based on a person model, we would potentially have a route to list all records.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('people');
});
```

With this map, I'm telling my app that it needs a people template (and maybe a view), a people controller and a people route. A resource is also assumed to have a index route, which is implied and you don't have to code it, but if you need to, it would be `PeopleIndexRoute`, after the name of the resource itself, by convention.

Now I can (a) create a `person` route under `people` resource to be a single state of a person record; or (b) I can create a `person` resource under the `people` resource, so I would have more options under `person` resource (edit, detail, delete); or (c) I could create a separate resource for person, and use the path to override the url if I want to.

I sometimes go for option c:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('people');
    this.resource('person', {path: 'person/:person_id'}, function() {
        this.route('edit');
        this.route('delete');
    });
});
```

That would make sense that `edit` is route since it doesn't have child states , only siblings (delete) and a parent (person). The url for a record would be something like this: `~/#/person/3/edit`).

The routes, when not defined as a resource, won't have any child route/state, so you don't have person.edit.index like you have person.index, in other words, routes don't have child, only siblings and resources can have both.

Right now, the [Routing Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) is the most solid piece of documentation we have about this. I strongly recommend it.

---

Dynamic Segment is a part of a route URL which changes according to the resource in use. Consider the following:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('products', function() {
        this.route('product', { path: ':product_id' })
    }
});
```

In the stub above, the line:

```
this.resource('products', function() {
```

will produce the url

> ~/#/products

and the following line will produce

> ~/#/products/:product_id

replacing the dynamic part, you could have an url like this

> ~/#/products/3

the `:product_id` is what makes this route dynamic. The router will serialize the id of a resource (for example a `Product` model) to the URL and it also uses that id to `find` the a model in your `DS.Store`. You'll often see this in routes like the following:

```
App.ProductRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Product.find(params.product_id);
    }
});
```

So for this example, if you access `~/#/products/3`, the app will then try to load an instance of the Product model from your store or try to fetch from your backend API.

You can see a fiddle that illustrates that [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/schawaska/bw45L/show) | [source here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/schawaska/bw45L)

I also recommend this [screencast by Tom Dale](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0&index=13) where he builds a blog reader app with Ember.js using the router and the ember-data API to load blog records based on the dynamic part of the URL.

Comment: Joe, thanks for answering so quickly! I keep on feedbacking to follow your explanation: where do the `map(..)`, `resource(..)`, and `route(..)` functions come from? I can't find them on the [`Ember.Router` API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html), where I'd expect them to be documented.

Comment: I don't think the Router API is fully documented because it's going through some re-write if I'm not mistaken. I think you should be checking the [Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) instead

Comment: So to grasp the semantics of those functions I can't count on any API documentation contract currently, but instead am left with reading those function's source code?... It's not clear to me what that callback inside the callback is good for. Phew.

Comment: I feel your pain. This is due to the fact that Ember changed a lot during a relatively short period of time. The API will probably receive more attention before the framework is released as final.

Comment: We are getting closer to an accepted answer :)... With respect to [the  screencast from 11:06 until 11:58](http://youtu.be/Ga99hMi7wfY?t=11m6s): For the "nested route", your provided code uses `this.route(...)`, while the screencast uses `this.resource(...)`. Is there any difference between `this.route(...)` and `this.resource(...)`?

Comment: For anyone curious:  

`App.Router.map(..)` comes from [`Ember.Router.map(..)`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L235). ... 

`this.resource(..)` comes from [`Ember.RouterDSL.resource(..)`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js#L12). ... 

`this.route(..)` comes from [`ember.RouterDSL.route(..)`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.2/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js#L42).

Comment: This is so WELL explained compared to what I found on the official docs. The exemples help a lot. Thanks.